# mvvmcross xamarin android hangs while loading

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, mvvmcross, samsung-mobile

I'm using MvvmCross 5.6.3, VS 2017, debugging on Samsung S4.
The splash screen displays "Loading..." but the first ViewModel does not display.
The debug output window shows:
`[0:] mvx:Diagnostic:  2.99 Setup: Secondary end
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
03-01 21:03:44.500 D/Mono    (24569): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_field_id'.
03-01 21:03:44.510 D/Mono    (24569): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
03-01 21:03:44.510 D/Mono    (24569): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
03-01 21:03:44.510 D/Mono    (24569): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
03-01 21:03:44.510 D/Mono    (24569): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_object_field'.
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
The thread 0x4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #2`

and continues creating/finishing threads.
Because of `Debug` statements I can see that the `Initialize` method in `App.cs` completed.

Question:
Are there techniques/tools that will reveal where the code is looping?

Thank you,
Marc